# gcov line count is different from no of lines in source code

Tags: gcc, gcov, lcov

output of gcov says no of lines executed 70 % of 10

but my code has more than 10 lines..

it does not count braces , else statement

please help ..

Answer (score 1):

`gcov` only counts lines of code that actually make it into the binary - braces are just part of the syntax.

Presumably the `else` is being optimized/compiled out?